# building make,gcc,buildessential packages

Tags: gcc, make

As we don't want to install build-essential make 4.1 and gcc-9.4.0 via apt-get install.
we need to compile source build-essential make 4.1 and gcc-9.4.0 in ubuntu. may I know where do I get these source packages?(links)
please let me know the compilation steps for the above.

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu and why not install the apps?

Comment: You can download the source using `apt source`   if you're using a Ubuntu system... *I do note the partial package versions you mention do **not** align with any supported release of Ubuntu*

Comment: @David we are making container based app and no need to run packages via "apt"

Comment: Please provide OS, product & release details

Comment: How to build gcc-9.4.0 and make : You will need "build-essential" to compile gcc, etc. → `sudo apt install g++ make autoconf libtool gawk flex bison binutils-dev libelf-dev texinfo zlib1g-dev` ...... Example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DnxKV_MOGJDwZ0mDIARrooYf9kUDPQlv/view?usp=sharing